# Abline not showing for plots in loop

Tags: r

When I run `abline(h=0)` within a loop it will not add a line at the horizontal, for example:

```
library(glue)
library(magrittr)
par(mfrow=n2mfrow(4, 2))
for(i in 1:4){
    plot(savings[, i], savings[,1], xlab = glue('predictor: {i}'), ylab = 'Dependent variable') %>%
        with(abline(h=0))
}
```

[image]

Here's some sample data:

```
savings <- structure(list(sr = c(11.43, 12.07, 13.17, 5.75, 12.88, 8.79, 
0.6, 11.9, 4.98, 10.78, 16.85, 3.59, 11.24, 12.64, 12.55), pop15 = c(29.35, 
23.32, 23.8, 41.89, 42.19, 31.72, 39.74, 44.75, 46.64, 47.64, 
24.42, 46.31, 27.84, 25.06, 23.31), pop75 = c(2.87, 4.41, 4.43, 
1.67, 0.83, 2.85, 1.34, 0.67, 1.06, 1.14, 3.93, 1.19, 2.37, 4.7, 
3.35), dpi = c(2329.68, 1507.99, 2108.47, 189.13, 728.47, 2982.88, 
662.86, 289.52, 276.65, 471.24, 2496.53, 287.77, 1681.25, 2213.82, 
2457.12), ddpi = c(2.87, 3.93, 3.82, 0.22, 4.56, 2.43, 2.67, 
6.51, 3.08, 2.8, 3.99, 2.19, 4.32, 4.52, 3.44)), row.names = c("Australia", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Canada", "Chile", 
"China", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Denmark", "Ecuador", "Finland", 
"France", "Germany"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Isn’t the abline just the x axis in this case?

Comment: Yes. Try `abline(h=0, col="red")` and you will see it.

Comment: Delete `%>%` and `with()`. `plot(...)` should be one line, `abline(h = 0)` should be the next. No `%>%` pipe, no `with()`.

Comment: Such issues are almost always because the line is not within the x-y range of the plot. You are mixing two R "universes". So I did add a library call to load `pkg:magrittr` to get your operator to work. You incorrectly assumed that R base plots would have a code-object available for adding items. That's not the base graphic model. R base graphics is all side-effects, pen&ink. I don't know how lattice graphics would respond to the new "|>" operator.

Comment: @IRTFM Turns out I had an issue with the plot itself, the y-values were not properly proportional as they kept changing they should remain fixed. After fixing this, then I solved the issue. This was only sample data, on the real thing this created the issue. Although as dcarlson mentioned, I saw the lines after increasing the image for this particular reproducible example.